# How to approach implementing a custom page header for each page

Tags: theming, entities, i18n-l10n

I am building a site that gives the content managers the ability to craft a masthead image, teaser text, and headline text for each individual page. This will appear in an area outside of node.tpl and -- anyway -- can also appear on taxonomy index pages, etc.

My current approach involves creating a Header content type and adding an EntityReference field to each entity I use in the site, then modifying page.tpl.php to look for and render that field. But is there a smarter approach?

**Edited**

The site is a multilingual site, so I'm looking for something that supports i18n. That lets Field Collection out, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to look at a solution using Minipanels.

Minipanels are basically [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels) (shipped together) that can be used as a block.

You could create a minipanel with the required content and assign that block to the header region for a particular page.

Alternatively, you could set it up as a content type with an image, title and teaser and then a template or view mode to render it in the header.

Comment: The minipanels option sounds pretty good, especially since the content manager may want to run the same header over an entire section, while tailoring headers to individual pages as needed. I can see the block management getting to be pretty hairy though depending on the number of unique panels.

Comment: Yes, a consideration will be how many pages / variations of these headers there will be. If there are a lot of them, maybe easier to use a templated node instead.

Comment: I think if I take my original plan for node and taxonomy pages, then use a block-based approach like you've suggested for pages that don't have that field, I will have covered all the required bases. Thanks!